# Get-Content Add-Content Starting at newline in a TXT file, powershell

Tags: powershell, newline

I have 2 txt files

Allunique.txt

```
cat
dog
```

Alluniquetemp.txt

```
fish
camel
```

If I issue the command

```
Get-Content -Path ....\Clean\Alluniquetemp.txt | Add-Content -Path ...\Clean\Allunique.txt
```

Allunique.txt becomes

```
cat
dogfish
camel
```

Now of coarse nobody wants a dogfish, I would much prefer Allunique.txt to become

```
cat
dog
fish
camel
```

Any help please?

Comment: your 1st file appears to lack a newline at the end of the last line of text. the file oriented cmdlets _expect_ properly ended lines ... and that one seems to lack such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the files aren't created with `Add-Content` (or `Set-Content`), otherwise they would have ended with a newline...

Anyways maybe not very effective from a performance point of view, but you might just recreated the `Allunique.txt` and add the other file, like:

```
(Get-Content .\Allunique.txt, Alluniquetemp.txt) | Set-Content .\Allunique.txt
```

Note that the brackets are required for this as you need to read and write to the the same (`.\Allunique.txt`) file.